# VBA for Connecting already opned IE window

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, createobject

I'm trying to connect to already opened IE window, but I have some problem at 2nd line

> `Run time error 429 ActiveX Component can't create object`

I have added references also still not able to access the IE window. Below is the code.

```
Sub A()
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
  For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
     my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    if my_title Like "Put your webpage title here" & "*" Then 
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things -

1. Declare 'ie' in your code.
2. IE_Count

   `IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count` should be `IE_count =
   objShell.Windows().Count`. Please refer -
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773969(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope correcting these will get your code working